# Reading string resources from satellite assemblies in Wix?

Tags: resources, wix, windows-installer, wix3, satellite-assembly

Is it possible through WIX to read resources from resource DLLs than hard-coding the strings in WXS/WXL files?
I have the resources in satellite DLLs and I need something more efficient then copying and hard-coding them in WXS/WXL files.

Thanks

Comment: If this is a build-time instead of a run-time thing, writing a WiX extension should allow you to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to get strings from resource DLL and then store them in properties using Custom Action. Then you can use these properties to display text in dialogs.

But I wouldn't advise using this approach. If these strings are meant to be used only during installation, then they should better go to WSX or WXL files: it is more straightforward and efficient.

Comment: So it is custom actions only then, I was looking for some inbuilt support from wix. thanks

Comment: @user4444 As far as I know, there's no such support. MSI is a database. All localized strings are also stored in this database. And you can apply a transform to translate the UI (this can be done even on the fly without creating a new package).